# Which is better - with which or with whom?

Tags: pronoun

In German, is there a preferred way of saying `with whom` or `with which`?

For example,

> **Die jungen Kinder, mit wem ich arbeite, sind schikaniert worden.**
>
> *The young children, with whom I work, have been bullied.*

Or is this construction better? It seems less personal to me, as if I were not to know them.

> **Die jungen Kinder, mit den ich arbeite, sind schikaniert worden.**
>
> *The young children, with which I work, have been bullied.*

Comment: Just a comment on your subject line: I find it a bit confusing - after all, you are NOT asking after "which" or "whom", but after the German equivalents/translations. As the question stands, I interpret it as a question about English grammar, which would be off topic.m

Comment: And that also applies to parts of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentence requires a dative relative pronoun which in this case would be *denen* because *die jungen Kinder* is plural. So correct would be

> Die jungen Kinder, mit denen ich arbeite, sind schikaniert worden.

Answer (score 0):

German does not have distinct personal pronouns like English, only relative pronouns, with the exception that *damit*, *womit* cannot be used of persons; *mit dem* or *mit den* is used instead. You have to rely on context.